# Как правильно читать?

Tags: общие-вопросы

**Выдержка из приказа:**

> Сотрудникам могут быть присвоены квалификационные звания специалиста третьего класса, специалиста второго класса, специалиста первого класса и мастера (высшее квалификационное звание):
>   специалист третьего класса - сотрудникам, прослужившим в ФПС ГПС не менее трех лет (если при этом не изменялось направление служебной деятельности) или имеющим стаж (опыт) работы по специальности не менее 2 лет и выдержавшим квалификационные испытания на оценку не ниже "хорошо" по всем видам профессиональной и физической подготовки...

**Вопрос:**
Нужно ли сотрудникам, прослужившим в ФПС ГПС не менее трех лет сдавать зачеты (квалификационные испытания) или им присваивается квалификация без испытаний за сам факт службы 3 года?

Answer (score 1):

Здесь союз "и", соответственно, для получения квалификации нужно и прослужить 3 года, и сдать зачёты. Невыполнение хотя бы одного из условий не даёт право на получение квалификации.

> Сотрудникам, прослужившим (...) и выдержавшим...

Comment: Согласен..."и"-соединительный союз, объединяющий 2 условия, но я думаю, что он соединяет условия второй части текста после союза "или" как раз разделительного, т.е. "или" разделяет текст на 2 условия: служишь 3 года и получаешь квалификацию или имеешь стаж 2 года+ испытания и также получаешь квалификацию Или я заблуждаюсь??

Answer (score 0):

Согласен с Яzz.Здесь: для получения квалификации нужно выполнить все условия контракта.